# Fluent NHibernate mixed mapping properties

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use fluent nhibernate to auto map most properties of a class, and then manually map 1 or 2 properties of that same class (without having to manually map all the other variables in the class map).

I have a class with a couple of dozen properties, but one of those properties is a string which needs to be a long length.

Here's an example:

Person class has fields: ID, firstname, lastname, description, and a few dozen other fields.

I would auto map the class but I want 'description' to be a long string, not a nvarchar(255).

So I try:

public class PersonMap : ClassMap
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.description).Length(4000);
        }
    }

but this doesn't auto map all the other properties (an exception is thrown).  It's expecting declarations for each property.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

If anyone needs it, here's the code I'm using to declare the configuration:

```
FluentConfiguration cfg = Fluently.Configure()
.Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2000.ConnectionString(Cn));
        AutoPersistenceModel mdl = 
            AutoMap.Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        cfg.Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(mdl.Where(type =>
        type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.ToLower() == strNamespace.ToLower() )));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out.  There's a method called 'override' that I can use when declaring the configuration, and in there I can specify all the overrides for specific properties:

```
AutoPersistenceModel mdl = AutoMap.Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

mdl.Override<MyNamespace.Person>(map =>
{
    map.Map(x => x.description).Length(4000);
});
```